# Retrieve matching strings from two text files

Tags: powershell

I have a text file `file_paths.txt` that contains full paths on each line:

```
C:\MyFolder1\app1.exe
C:\MyFolder2\l1.dll
C:\MyFolder3\app2.exe
C:\MyFolder1\l2.dll
C:\MyFolder5\app3.exe
C:\MyFolder3\app4.exe
C:\MyFolder6\app5.exe
```

I also have file `folders.txt` that contains list of folders:

```
C:\MyFolder1
C:\MyFolder2
C:\MyFolder3
C:\MyFolder4
C:\MyFolder8
```

I need to iterate through the list of folders in `folders.txt`, match it with files in `file_paths.txt` and write the results to a file `result.txt` like this:

```
In C:\MyFolder1 more than one files has been found:
    C:\MyFolder1\app1.exe
    C:\MyFolder1\l2.dll

In C:\MyFolder2 one file has been:
    C:\MyFolder2\l1.dll

In C:\MyFolder3 more than one files has been found:
    C:\MyFolder3\app2.exe
    C:\MyFolder3\app4.exe

In C:\MyFolder4 no files has been found.

In C:\MyFolder8 no files has been found.
```

My attempt that doesn't work:

```psh
$paths = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("file_paths.txt")
$folders = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("folders.txt")
$result = "result.txt"
try {
    for(;;) {
        $folder = $folders.ReadLine()
        if ($folder -eq $null) { break }
        "In ">> $folder >> ": `n" >> $result
        for(;;) {
           $path = $paths.ReadLine()
           if ($path -eq $null) { break }
           if ($path -contains $folder) {"  ">>$path>>"`n">>$result }
        }
    }
} finally {
    $paths.Close()
    $folders.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate processing from reporting. First build a hashtable from the contents of `folders.txt` and add the lines from `file_paths.txt` to the matching keys:

```
$folders = @{}
Get-Content 'folders.txt' | ForEach-Object { $folders[$_] = @() }

Get-Content 'file_paths.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $line = $_
  $($folders.Keys) | Where-Object {
    $line -like "$_*"
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $folders[$_] += $line
  }
}
```

Then you can output the resulting data structure like this:

```
$folders.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  'In {0} {1} files have been found' -f $_, $folders[$_].Count
  if ($folders[$_].Count -gt 0) {
    $folders[$_] | ForEach-Object { "`t$_" }
  }
} | Out-File 'result.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a script you can use to do exactly what you need.
Note the `$folderPath` and `$filePath` variables. Replace with absolute or relative (to where you execute the script) path of the `file_paths.txt` and `folders.txt` files.

```
$folderPath = 'folders.txt'
$filePath = 'file_paths.txt'

(Get-Content $folderPath).Split('`r`n') | ForEach-Object {
    $folder = $_
    $count = 0
    $fileArray = @()
    (Get-Content $filePath).Split('`r`n') | ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        if( $file | Select-String $folder -Quiet ) {
            $count++
            $fileArray += $file
        }
    }
    if($count -ne 0) {
        Write-Output "In $folder, $count files has been found."
        $fileArray | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Output "`t$_"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "In $folder, no files has been found."
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-Content` already splits a file into a list of lines (unless used with the parameter `-Raw`). No need to use ``Split('`r`n')`` here.